# NSTableViewCell setSelected?

Tags: storyboard, swift2, nstableview, osx-elcapitan, nstablecellview

How do I communicate between my **NSViewController** and the **NSTableViewCell** when I select that cell on my tableView?
On iOS you could use setSelected but in OSX it is totally different.
The NSTableCellView class doesn't have any function like that. I might be missing something simple. How do I talk with that cell? I have a custom class cell and on my tableView controller, I got:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {

    let previousSelected = NSIndexSet(index: selectedRow)
    selectedRow = row
    let indset = NSIndexSet(index: row)

    // animate row expansion
    self.tableView.noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged(indset)

    // animate back the previously selected
    self.tableView.noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged(previousSelected)
    return true
}
```

I also have the height of Row...

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if row == selectedRow{
        return 90
    }else{
        return 40
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to let my cell know it got selected, so it can display different things when selected. Anyone ?

Comment: You want to select a cell programmatically (not by a user initiated action)?

Comment: No. I just want the Cell class - NSTableCellView to know when it got selected. I'm not sure if its the ViewController that lets the cell know it got selected or if there is a method in the cell class that runs when the cell gets selected and what method would that be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection doesn't operate on cells, it operates on rows. `NSTableRowView` has a `selected` property. It's generally responsible for drawing the selected appearance of table rows with its `drawSelectionInRect()` method.

How exactly does your cell change its behavior or appearance based on whether it's selected? Are you sure that shouldn't be done by the row, instead? Perhaps you should be using a custom subclass of `NSTableRowView`.

If you must, you can find the row view from the cell view. One way is to just assume the cell's superview is the row view, which it should be when it's not `nil`. Another approach is to ask the table view which row the cell is for using `rowForView(self)` and then ask the table view for the row view using `rowViewAtRow(_:makeIfNecessary:)`.

Comment: perfect. It works! i get the row, then get the cell and then I can let the cell class to know it's been chosen by adding a var:selected:Bool like @NicolasMiari mentioned. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

`NSTableCellView` does not seem to have a `selected` property. Perhaps you can subclass it and add such property.

Then, implement the delegate method:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
        shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool
```

...and in the cases when you return `true` (i.e., the row should be selected), set the `selected` property you just defined of the corresponding cell to `true`.

If you want the cell to do something when selected, define your property like this:

```
var selected:Bool {
    didSet {
        if selected {
            // Act accordingly...
        }
    }
}
```