# tableview image content selection color

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, colors, tableview

My app has a tableview with an image and a textfield:

- image = image render as template image (light grey)
- textfield = text color black

If I select a row, the color of both will change perfectly to white

Question - I change the image to a blue color image = render as default.
If I now select a row, the text color of my textfield will change to white, but the image will stay blue.

I want the image change the color to white too but it doesn't.

What did I do wrong?

**Example with an image render as template mode => default: grey | selected automatically white**

[image]

**Example with an colored image render as default mode => default: green | selected also green | expected white, but it stay green**

[image]

Comment: Isn't this same question? Respectively same solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249456/nstableviewcell-setselected

Comment: i guess this is is not the same situation, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not expert in macOS, but my guess is create custom subclass of NSTableCellView and in var selected in didSet handle by your own the highlighting or another related action.

Comment: is this the correct way? i can't believe that this is so complicated

Comment: I really would like to say yes or no, but I don't know. This is just some way, how to do it. When you figure it out, if its correct or not, please write it here. I'm really curious.

Comment: could you provide your code? I just tested your scenario and it worked for me

Comment: can you send my your example ? my example isn't available yet :(

Comment: @Ghost108 Can you please show me show image of your expected output?

Comment: I updated my first post with an example

Comment: @Ghost108, did you find OSX solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView:NSTableView!
    var selectIndex = -1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tintedImage(_ image: NSImage, tint: NSColor) -> NSImage {
        guard let tinted = image.copy() as? NSImage else { return image }
        tinted.lockFocus()
        tint.set()

        let imageRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, .sourceAtop)

        tinted.unlockFocus()
        return tinted
    }
}

extension ViewController:NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate{
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{


        let result = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "imageIcon", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        if selectIndex == row{
            result.imageView?.image = self.tintedImage(NSImage(named:"file")!, tint: NSColor.green)

        }else{
            result.imageView?.image = self.tintedImage(NSImage(named:"file")!, tint: NSColor.gray)

        }
        return result

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {
        if selectIndex == row{
            rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue
        }else{
            rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        }
    }


    func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let table = notification.object as! NSTableView
        self.selectIndex = tableView.selectedRow

        print(table.selectedRow);
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

> Note: Change imageView tintColor color as per your requirement.

[image: table row selection with color]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i need a osx solution :(

Comment: unbelievable that a osx solution is so complicated. in iOS it is much easier :/

Comment: Have you tried? Let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: yea i tried this a few days ago. this solution i found also on stack overflow. but i can't believe hat this have to be so much complicated. and i guess hat your code `tableViewSelectionDidChange` doesn't work. i tried this and if i put my `outlineView.reloadData()` in this function, the selection will always change by calling reloadData => loop :(

Comment: @Ghost108 Don't call `reloadData`, check the documentation for a method to reload one cell.

Comment: Instead of `reloadData`, in `tableViewSelectionDidChange` use [`enumerateAvailableRowViewsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1532750-enumerateavailablerowviewsusingb) which operates only on the currently needed rows, not all, and is thus quite performant.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom cell and override the `setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool)` to change the iamgeView's tintColor :

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    imageView?.tintColor = highlighted ? UIColor.white : UIColor.green
}
```

Then, when you create your cell, you set the image with an `UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = CustomCell()
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "custom_image")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    cell.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.green
    return cell
}
```

Comment: and again: i need a osx solution

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never.

Here's my solution which a friend helped me with. Implement a custom `NSImageCell` class and override `interiorBackgroundStyle`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TFSelectStateImageCell : NSImageCell

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```
#import "TFSelectStateImageCell.h"

@implementation TFSelectStateImageCell


- (NSBackgroundStyle)interiorBackgroundStyle {
    NSBackgroundStyle style = [super interiorBackgroundStyle];
    self.image.template = (style == NSBackgroundStyleEmphasized);
    return style;
}

@end
```

This way you get the benefits of the `template` property for an `NSImage` when the row is selected, but when it's not selected, you get your full colour image.

Comment: I could kiss you, my friend ... I was really struggling with this problem, and you saved the day :) Upvoted ... this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yup. it's a very simple solution, but something that's not so obvious.