# tableview image color changes with short delay

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, colors, nstableview

This question is a addition of this topic: [tableview image content selection color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922699/tableview-image-content-selection-color)

All works fine, but one little thing bothers me.
This is the result:

[image]

You can see that the default color of the image is grey.
If you select a row, the image should change the color to white - it works! but you can see a short delay before it will change the color (I hope you see what I mean)

Can I optimize it?

This is my Code:

```
// Change Color of Image
    func tintedImage(_ image: NSImage, tint: NSColor) -> NSImage {
        guard let tinted = image.copy() as? NSImage else { return image }
        tinted.lockFocus()
        tint.set()

        let imageRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
        imageRect.fill(using: .sourceAtop)

        tinted.unlockFocus()
        return tinted
    }


func outlineViewSelectionIsChanging(_ notification: Notification) {

   if lastSelectedRow != nil {
      let view = myOutlineView.view(atColumn: 0, row: lastSelectedRow!, makeIfNecessary: true) as! CustomCell
                    view.imgView.image = self.tintedImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "MyImage"))!, tint: NSColor.grey)
                }

                lastSelectedRow = myOutlineView.selectedRow

    }

 func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {


            let view = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell"), owner: self) as? CustomCell

            if lastSelectedRow == outlineView.selectedRow {
                view?.imgView.image = self.tintedImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "MyImage"))!, tint: NSColor.white)
            } else {
                view?.imgView.image = self.tintedImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "MyImage"))!, tint: NSColor.grey)
            }



            return view
}
```

Comment: Please add code for cell for row

Comment: i used the code in the another topic, which i selected as the correct answer

Comment: Yes I understand , But you should put your code for better understanding that what you have actually did, Anyway this is separate question

Comment: Ok i will do it later

Comment: add your code for better clarity

Comment: i updated my first post with the code

Comment: Rather than setting the value of `lastSelectedRow` in `outlineViewSelection IsChanging:` you could try setting it in the delegate method `outlineView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection`.

Comment: what should I do in this methode ? `lastSelectedRow = outlinview.selectedRow`? and which IndexSet should I return?

Comment: **The method's documentation provides succinct answers to both of your questions**. `proposedSelectionIndexes` is *an index set containing the indexes of the proposed selection*; so set `lastSelectedRow` to the first index in this set (assuming (i) the set isn't  empty, and (ii) you can't select more than one row). You then just need to return `proposedSelectionIndexes`.